# PANIC: Missing arch-specific emulator program: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools/emulator-mips.exe

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I just install the mips system image in my Android SDK Manager.
When I run an AVD with CPU/ABI - with mips system image. It gives me the error and AVD doesn't launch.
Please take a look at the images.

Also can anyone tell me what is mips system image.[image]

[image]

------------- also see my SDK manager --------

It says that mips system image is installed on your system.

-[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably due to running version 20 or older of the SDK tools. They added mips into 21 which is in their preview channel. To enable the preview channel you just need to open your SDK Manager, click on Tools->Options and then check Enable Preview Tools.

http://developer.mips.com/android/download-android-sdk/

http://tools.android.com/preview-channel

Comment: Thanks. But that option is not available in Linux (I'm running Fedora 17 GNOME, SDK 20.0.3).

Comment: Please check again. I just created a new Fedora 17 64-bit VM, installed the SDK and it does have Enable Preview Tools. The screen was shrinking the dialog window down so I did have to expand it to see the option but it was there.

Comment: Thank you. The dialog box is "collapsed" as you said. I make it taller and I can see the option now. It's great  :-)

Answer (score 0):

see if your .exe file is in your antivirus quarantine

1- Download the adt-bundle again from https://developer.android.com/tools/sdk.
2- Open the Zip File.
3- Copy the missing .exe Files From the Folder "\sdk\tools".
4- Past the Copied Files in Your "Android\sdk\tools" Directory.

Answer (score -3):

Please go to

- Android Virtual Device Manager using the Eclipse IDE.
- Windows -> AVD Manager.
- Select the AVD desired from the list and click on the 'Start' button.